# Why old red value persist in the browser, using XMLHttp request object?

Tags: javascript, xml

I am reading a comma separated text file from the server, i get the valuse but when i chage the comma seprated variables in the file, it doesn't load the correct result int the browser 
while browser persist the first time variable list only, whlile it works correct in IE, in firefox i am facig this proble.
How to sort it out

```
var arrUserTags = new Array();
                            var txt;
                            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            xmlhttp.open("GET", "/TinyEditor/TextFile.txt", true);
                            xmlhttp.send();

                            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                                    txt = xmlhttp.responseText;
                                    arrUserTags = txt.split(",");
                                    alert(arrUserTags.length);
                                    parse();

                                }
                            }

                            // Add some values to the list box
                            function parse() {
                                for (i = 0; i < arrUserTags.length; i++) {
                                    mlb.add(arrUserTags[i], arrUserTags[i]);
                                    alert('hi');
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: When i remove browser history. it works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You server is presumably sending [caching instructions](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) that tell browsers the URI for the text file won't change for a while.

Either configure the server to send *no cache* headers, or change the URI (e.g. by adding a `rand()` query string to it).